# What is the meaning of Globe icon in Google Chrome keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

I've disabled functional keys and got this icon in Google Chrome.

What is the meaning this icon, which key to press?

[image]

Comment: What is the make/model of Mac that you are using?

Comment: @NimeshNeema It's A2141 model, the keyboard doesn't have globe icon on fn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Globe icon is representing the Globe key found on the newer generation of Mac keyboards.

On newer generation of Mac keyboards, the Globe key is analogous to the Fn key found on previous generation Mac keyboards. The key can be found on the bottom left hand corner and shows both the `Fn` as well as the Globe  character.

### Magic Keyboard with TouchID

[image]

### Magic Keyboard without TouchID

[image]

### M1 MacBook Air

[image]

### 13" M1 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar

[image]

### 14"/16" MacBook Pro

[image]

---

From the Apple support document on Magic Keyboard:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/imac/apd0e7983e19/2021/mac/12

> **Set keyboard preferences.** To specify options for your keyboard and the Function (Fn)/Globe key , open System Preferences, click Keyboard, and choose options to change your keyboard or input source, show emoji and symbols, start dictation, or define functions.